# View doesn't update even after using Scope.apply

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

```
$('#list').scroll(function () 
{
    var that = MainController.that;
    if (that.colorIsVisible) 
    {
        var allColors: Array<ColorSingle> = that.GetColors();
        for (var a = 0; a < 10; a++) 
        {
            if (allColors.length > that.currentColors.length) 
                that.currentColors.push(allColors[that.currentColors.length]);
            else
                break;
        }
    }
    that.$scope.$apply();
});
```

I have a very long list of colors, and I am taking the approach of Infinite Scrolling. I tried to mock up this behavior by writing the code above. What happens is whenever I scroll, the scope variable (currentColors) is getting updated. Whenever I look at the view, however, no elements are added.

The view code is:

```
div ng-repeat="color in pdp.currentColors">
```

The actual currentColors value is getting updated. It's just not displaying in the view.

Comment: what's the error in the console?

Comment: There isn't an error in the console